# Change Android webview content (hash) without reloading the url

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have 2 webviews : Webview1 and Webview2 (say). The user arrives at Webview1 (an url loads). Now when the user clicks on Webview2, I need to load a url like www.abcd.com#Page1. Now when the user traverses to the second page in Webview1, I need to load www.abcd.com#Page2 in Webview2. Likewise, when the user traverses through pages in Webview1, I need to change the content in Webview2 accordingly.

But if I use `Webview2.loadurl()` everytime, it takes time to load. Instead I want to just change the content without reloading it.

**Note** : I get the values #Page1, #Page2 etc from Webview1, so don't bother about it. Please let me know how to achieve this without reloading the new url everytime in Android webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out :

Load the webview initially with the url (say `www.abcd.com#Page1`).  Now whenever you want to update the url like `www.abcd.com#Page2` (Hash value changes from Page1 to Page2), just do the following :

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("location.hash=\"" + url + "\";", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                if(Debugging.Enabled) Log.d(TAG(), "onReceiveValue(value): " + value);
                }
        });
```

where url is the new hash value. i.e. Page2. Webview loads pretty fast :)

Comment: Note: Please be sure to escape the URL or users can be tricked into executing arbitrary JavaScript by simply adding a `"; <evil code>;"`